# Deleting the same row number across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

I’m looking for a macro that will delete the same row number based on row selection on multiple sheets when I delete that row(s) from sheet1. Example: if I delete row 5 on sheet1, I want row 5 deleted on sheet2 automatically, whether tables exist or not. Can anyone assist?

Comment: Note: I have 4 sheets in my workbook.  2 of which are hidden.  I only want this macro to apply to the visible sheets.

Comment: Note that SO is not meant to be a code-writing service. Did you try anything yet?

Comment: I have tried a couple different macros, one of which I found on this site that is similar to what I'm trying to do but not exactly.

Sub WorksheetLoop()

     Dim WS_Count As Integer
     Dim I As Integer

     ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
     ' workbook.
     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

     ' Begin the loop.
     For I = 1 To WS_Count

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet(I).Rows(8).EntireRow.Delete
     Next I

  End Sub

That one is similar to what I'm trying to do but even this one I couldn't get to work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with that code, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your use is, but you can right-click your sheet and 'Select All Sheets', then when you delete a row from your active sheet it will also delete that row from all the selected sheets. This will not affect your hidden sheets.

Comment: What you just described is much less complicated that what I've been trying to do.  I'm going to create a delete button with that sequence in a macro and that appears like it will work perfectly for me.  Thank you!

Comment: Mind sharing what your code looks like when you get it working?